# jdbc javax.naming.NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jndi

I have been having a problem with this exception for a long time.  I am trying to connect to an external mysql database but I keep getting this exception.  I have looked at many examples and I still have not found the answer.  Here is my code, please bare in mind that this is all the code I use for this so please say if I've missed something out:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<context>
    <!-- Registers Database with JNDI Naming Service as a pooled DataSource -->
<Resource 
        name="jdbc/DBNAME" 
        auth="Container" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testOnReturn="false"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        validationInterval="30000"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
        maxActive="100" 
        minIdle="10" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        initialSize="10"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        logAbandoned="true"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
        jmxEnabled="true"
        jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
        username="****" 
        password="********"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://****:3306/****"/>

</context>
```

And here is my code for calling it:

```
try
{
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/DBNAME");
    Connection c = ds.getConnection();
    return c;
}
catch(NamingException ne)
{
    System.out.println(ne.toString());
    return null;
}
catch (SQLException se) 
{
    System.out.println(se.toString());
    return null;
}
```

Usernames, passwords, db urls and connection names have been redacted but the rest is correct.

Comment: Can you share your complete stacktrace?

Comment: Also have you added resource-ref in your web.xml

Comment: '<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/&&&&&&</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>'  This is what's in web.xml

Comment: your res-ref-name should be same as name. Please make both either jdbc/chitchat or jdbc/DBNAME

Comment: yes they are both the same I just redacted the name earlier on.

Answer (score 1):

From Tomcat doc at:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html

Try using this code:

```
Context ic= new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");

DataSource ds = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/DBNAME");
```

Regards.

Comment: I should add that I have tried this and I just tried it again.  This didn't work for me, same error.